# Parsing hyphenated XML file with Gradle

Tags: xml, gradle

I have an xml file like this --

```
<merge-requests type="array">
  <merge-request>
    <created-at type="datetime">2013-09-04T11:20:34Z</created-at>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2013-09-04T11:20:34Z</updated-at>
    <status>Open</status>
    <id>116</id>
  </merge-request>
  <merge-request>
    <created-at type="datetime">2013-09-03T22:50:30Z</created-at>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2013-09-03T22:50:30Z</updated-at>
    <status>Open</status>
    <id>115</id>
  </merge-request>
</merge-requests>
```

I want to be able to pull the IDs from each merge request.

Here is my gradle task:

```
task parseXml() {
  def mergeRequests = (new XmlParser()).parse('merge-requests.xml')
  mergeRequests.{'merge-request'}.each{ merge-request ->
    println "ID: " + merge-request@id
  }
}
```

This fails with:

```
Startup failed:
build file 'build.gradle': expecting '}', found '->'
```

I'm guessing this is because it cannot find the tag name.

Is this because of the hyphens or something I'm missing?

I tried creating and using a variable instead of using the full hyphenated name, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few issues with your build script; using hyphens in variable names, excessive use of braces for parsed elements, and you have defined the task to run at configuration stage rather than when it's called, is this what you really wanted?

I've avoided the @ notation of the Node, which avoids one of the compilation issues, and here's a working solution:

```
task parseXml << {
    def mergeRequests = (new XmlParser()).parse('merge-requests.xml')
    mergeRequests.'merge-request'.each { m ->
        println "ID: " + m.id[0].text()
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
$ gradle parseXml
:parseXml
ID: 116
ID: 115
```